# Gong WPF Drag Drop Implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, drag-and-drop

I'm having trouble implementing gong wpf dragdrop. I am trying to DD between two list boxes, each connected to a collectionview source with source set to an observablecollection(Of Item) where Item is not a simple type, like the string type used in the example, but a class which is an entity framework entity. These have long complex names because they are EF proxies, but I have confirmed that both are the same type. I've wired them up and I can reorder items in either list, but I cannot move items from one list to the other. Should the default handlers work in this case and if not, what do I have to do? Or, how do I troubleshoot this. Thanks.